# Concatenating Names, Instruments, and Birthdays of the RHCP

Tags: python, concatenation, python-datetime

so I'm trying to accomplish what my title suggests. I stored their names and instruments in a list. I attempted to change their birthdays to a string so I could concatenate it with the other two lists.

```
Members = ["Flea", "John Frusciante", "Jack Irons", "Anthony Kiedis"]
Instruments = ["Bassist", "Guitarist", "Drummer", "Musician"]
Birthdates = str([10/16/1962, 3/5/1970, 7/18/1962, 11/1/1962])

New_list = [a + " is the " + b + " and they were born on " + c for a, b, c in zip(Members, Instruments, Birthdates)]
print "\n".join(New_list)
```

My result is a bit confusing since I'm not receiving any errors. I was hoping that the dates might print out as they were recorded in the Birthdays list.

```
Flea is the Bassist and they were born on [
John Frusciante is the Guitarist and they were born on 0
Jack Irons is the Drummer and they were born on ,
Anthony Kiedis is the Musician and they were born on
```

I know I'm missing some steps between then and what I have currently, but my goal looks like this:

```
Flea is the Bassist and they were born on 16 October, 1962.
```

Comment: `10/16/1962` isn't a date, it's a numeric expression, equivalent to `(10 / 16) / 1962)`. In Python 2, that results in zero. In Python 3, you'd get 0.00031855249745158003 because in Python 3, `/` gives you true division.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just enter something like `10/16/1962` as naked text. That's a mathematical expression. When Python sees that, it immediately calculates the value of the expression, and that's what's in your list:

```
>>> 10/16/1962
0.00031855249745158003
```

If you want a date, you have to use a `date` object:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date(1962, 10, 16)
datetime.date(1962, 10, 16)
>>> str(date(1962, 10, 16))
'1962-10-16'
```

If you want to format it as `16 October, 1962`, you have to use `strftime()`:

```
>>> date(1962, 10, 16).strftime('%-m %B, %Y')
'10 October, 1962'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need remove `str` only if `datetime`s are `string`s:

```
Birthdates = ['10/16/1962', '3/5/1970', '7/18/1962', '11/1/1962']
```

And then convert strings to datetime and change format of output:

```
from datetime import datetime

New_list = ["{} is the {} and they were born on {:%d, %B %Y}".format(a,b,datetime.strptime(c, '%m/%d/%Y')) for a, b, c in zip(Members, Instruments, Birthdates)]
print ("\n".join(New_list))
Flea is the Bassist and they were born on 16, October 1962
John Frusciante is the Guitarist and they were born on 05, March 1970
Jack Irons is the Drummer and they were born on 18, July 1962
Anthony Kiedis is the Musician and they were born on 01, November 1962
```